# Mapping extended set of real numbers under fractional linear transformations??

Tags: linear-transformations, mobius-transformation

I have a function $f(z)=\frac{6z}{(1+3i)z-4i}$
and I want to map the set $R^*$ using the function $f(z)$; how can I do it?
I have written $f(z)$ into $x,y$ form as
$$w=\frac{6(x+iy)}{(1+3i)(x+iy)-4i}$$
now if I put $y=0$ into this function
I get $$w=\frac{6x}{(1+3i)(x)-4i}$$
How do I use this to find the image under $f$? I'm also uncertain how to sketch this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can expand $1/(a + i b)$ into the sum of the real and imaginary parts to get the curve $(\operatorname {Re} w, \operatorname {Im} w)$ parametrized by $x$, but that'll be messy. Just consider that $f(0) = 0$ and that if you know the point $z_0 \not \in \mathbb R^*$ which is mapped to $\infty$, then $\overline {z_0}$ is mapped to the center of the image circle.